# como puedo restar horas y mostrarlas en una tabla vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify

hola tengo dos horas de entrada y salida en una tabla vuetify y quiero restarlas ,mostrando el resultado en una columna con horas diarias y mensuales, el problema es que no tengo idea de como restar datos tipo time en JavaScript :

HTML:

```
<v-data-table
id="tabla"
dense
:headers="headers"
:items="desserts"
item-key="name"
:page.sync="page"
:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
hide-default-footer
@page-count="pageCount = $event"
>
</v-data-table>
```

JavaScript:

```
desserts: [
  {
  dia        :'1' ,
  horaEntMan : '' ,
  horaSalMan : '' ,
  horaEntTar : '' ,
  horaSalTar : '' ,
  horas      : '' ,
  observacion: '' ,
  },
  {
  dia        :'2' ,
  horaEntMan : '' ,
  horaSalMan : '' ,
  horaEntTar : '' ,
  horaSalTar : '' ,
  horas      : '' ,
  observacion: '' ,
  },
  {
  dia        :'3' ,
  horaEntMan : '' ,
  horaSalMan : '' ,
  horaEntTar : '' ,
  horaSalTar : '' ,
  horas      : '' ,
  observacion: '' ,
  },
  {
  dia        :'4' ,
  horaEntMan : '' ,
  horaSalMan : '' ,
  horaEntTar : '' ,
  horaSalTar : '' ,
  horas      : '' ,
  observacion: '' ,
  },
```

[image]

por ejemplo así es la tabla y quiero poder restar las horas de entrada con las horas de salida y mostrar el total en la columna horas

Answer (score 0):

Los datatable de vuetify se pueden manipular usando métodos de vue revisa este código en codepen https://codepen.io/Juan-Carlos-MA/pen/yLoNevw?editors=1010 ahí encontraras mi solución la cual usa JavaScript para modificar los elementos de la tabla haciendo uso de los métodos de vue como son mounted() {} y methods: {} si tienes dudas consulta la pagina de vue sobre uso de métodos propios.

[image: Codigo]